# inserting piechart to a crystal report

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I am working in c#.I want to create  crystal reports which need a pie chart to show on that report.
So can u just tell me (procedure or any example or any link )that how to insert  a graph to a crystal report.

eg. suppose there r some courses and their particular batches. Batches have their particular no of students.
Show a pie chart based on batches with no of students of a particular course.
given that all the values are from the same table.

```
On btn_click()

{   
            SqlConnection cnn;
            string connectionString = null;
            string sql = null;
            connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EMS;User ID,password=";

            cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            cnn.Open();
            sql = "query";

            SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
            DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
            dscmd.Fill(ds, "names");
            cnn.Close();
            CrystalReport1 objRpt = new CrystalReport1();
            objRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[1]);
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
            CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();    
}
```

Comment: You can also mark the comments as great or flag them if you find them spam , offensive or unconstructive. if u move your mouse on the comment you can see this mark.

Comment: As i have seen you have 5 question that have answered and you didn't accept them.

Comment: ok.thanx for remembrance....by the way can u send me any reference pages for my question?

Comment: Pls anubody can tell me...?actually i collect data from 2 tables.Therefore i need a datatable to collect it.my next question is how to show it on crystal report. because whenever i m going to show, program runs but it gives me double the no of columns i selected.because in design we also select a columns.I dnt hav any idea abt showing data on report from datatable.I m giving my code above on button click of aspx page.Do u have any idea abt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right Click in blank area of Report Designer and  then `Insert` and then click `Chart option`.
In the `Type` tab and from `chart type` list select `Pie` Option or any another type of Chart.